# PHP: Convert iso-8859-1-encoded characters to html-entities

Tags: php, html, iso-8859-1

I have a string like the following:

```
$test = "<div style=\"font-weight:bold;\">\334berraschung!</div>";
```

When I output this as it is on a web page, it displays correctly:

```
Überraschung!
```

...because \334 is the code for Ü in ISO-8859-1. But what I need, is the Html-Entity of the character (and of the whole string, so a replacement for all these ...-Characters), which in this case would be:

```
&Uuml;berraschung!
```

or even better the Unicode entity

```
&#220;berraschung!
```

How can I convert this in PHP?

Comment: Did you try [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) on it?

Comment: Yes, it did not work out for me - but I found out that probably this is the solution I am looking for:

    mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'pass')

...unfortunately I have now the problem that this works without problems when I instantiate the string as above, but when I get the string I have to convert out of the depths of the API of my application, it somehow does not work, though the output looks the same. So I'll have to work on it alittle bit further. ;-)